# Getting the previous value of a variable in a for loop and using it for the current selection

Tags: javascript, for-loop, math

I am trying to set a transform property on a set of SVGs so that they all stack on top of each other. The SVGs can be either 20px or 100px tall based on the chartType. Basically, the transform property (for Y) that is set for the previous item in the for loop should be able to be used as a baseline for the next item in the for loop.

What I have so far:

```
childrenCharts(10)
[{childName:"VitalsChart"},
{childName:"VitalsChart"},
{childName:"VitalsChart"},
{childName:"StepChart"},
{childName:"StepChart"},
{childName:"StepChart"},
{childName:"StepChart"},
{childName:"StepChart"},
{childName:"StepChart"},
{childName:"StepChart"},]

for (var i=0; i<childrenCharts.length; ++i) {
      currentName = childrenCharts[i].chartName;
      var sibHeight;
      console.log(sibHeight);
      var subtractor = i-1
      if (currentName === "StepChart") {
        var baseline = (childrenCharts.length-subtractor)*childHeight;
            sibHeight = baseline - 40;
      }
      else {
        childrenCharts[i].selection
             .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + (childrenCharts.length-i)*childHeight + ")"); 
        sibHeight = (childrenCharts.length-subtractor)*childHeight;  

      }         
    }
```

StepChart is the chart that is 20px and childHeight = 100px

Currently, sibHeight logs in the console:

1000 900 800 660 560 460 360 260

I need the actual sibHeights to be:

1000 900 800 660 620 580 540 500

Comment: I suspect this is because of variable hoisting in javascript, but I don't see why this would make any difference.  You never **use** the previous value on the right side of an `=`, you're always setting it to a new value. (Based on the code you are showing).

Comment: You are definitely correct about this. Any ideas on how to fix my code? I am having trouble getting the logic and math correct.